# How to open two different activity on recyclerView - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, onclicklistener

I am using a **recyclerView** to show a list of card-movies in the **mainActivity** and I have implemented an **onclickListener** that open the details page.

If I wanted one of the cards in the list to open a different activity, how can I set the click or, if necessary, the other elements I use?

Comment: you'd have to examine the data in the card in the click handler.  when movie.rating  G -> start activityG  PG -> start activityPG

Answer (score 0):

on your `onClick()` method call the position of the card as follows

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {          

    final Intent intent;
    switch (getAdapterPostion()){
        case 0:
           intent =  new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
           break;

        case 1:
            intent =  new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            break;
           ...
        default:
           intent =  new Intent(context, DefaultActivity.class);
           break;
     }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```